# Exception in thread "main"org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:session not created

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
package org.example;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import   org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
    public class Datatable {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public String baseurl="https://datatables.net/";`enter code here`

    public void find() throws Exception{
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Asus\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32 
    (2)\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(baseurl);
        List<WebElement> col=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"hero- 
        callout\"]//thead//tr//th"));
        System.out.println("No of columns are:"+(col.size()-1));
        List<WebElement> 
        row=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id=\"example\"]/tbody/tr/td[1]"));
        System.out.println("No of rows are:"+row.size());
```

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id=\"example_filter\"]//input[@type=\"search\"]")).sendKeys("Accountant");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id=\"example_filter\"]//input[@type=\"search\"]")).sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
            Datatable CHE=new Datatable();
            CHE.find();
        }
        //Reporter.log("Browser open");
        //Reporter.log("\n Screen maximised");
    }

Comment: Show error message like 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81

Answer (score 1):

*"This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81".*
The ChromeDriver version needs to match the Chrome version, so if you are on Chrome v81 you need to upgrade Chromedriver as well.

Some general rules on chosing the correct ChromeDriver version [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection).